# Facebook page tab thumb icon not showing for non-admins

Tags: facebook

I've made loads of page tabs, but since the changes to the developer center in December I'm having an issue where non-admins can't see the thumbnail icon for the newly created page tab. Weirdly they can in fact see the page tab if they go to the direct URL, they just don't get any icons linking to the tab. Only admins get them. The slider in the "status & review" section for making the tab live is set to "yes." I no longer see a "sandbox mode" option, I assumed this is the new sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question: Non-admins only get a maximum of 12 total page tab app slots. Admins can have more.